# Transfer data from android to java desktop application

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask, asyncsocket

I run an application in Android and a string value as an answer. Now I want to pass this result to the Java server which is on my localhost, i.e pass the value from Android code to Java desktop application.

I tried using this code, but when I run the client it says unfortunately the application has stopped.

It says:

```
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
```

I found from somewhere that I need to use `asynctask` for it. Can you please guide me on how to use `asynctask` here?

The IP address is my localhost's IP and port number is any random number.

I try to run the server and then the client. I even tried running client on emulator and on the actual device. The app closes. I am new to Android. What I am doing wrong?

Here's the code of the client:

```
    package com.example.client;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //reference to the text field
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //reference to the send button

    //Button press event listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

    messsage = textField.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
    textField.setText(""); //Reset the text field to blank

    try {

    client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444); //connect to server
    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
    printwriter.write(messsage); //write the message to output stream

    printwriter.flush();
    printwriter.close();
    client.close(); //closing the connection

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    });
    }}
```

And here's the code of the server:

```
    public class server {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); //Server socket

    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
    }

    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

    while (true) {
    try {

    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); //accept the client connection
    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
    message = bufferedReader.readLine();

    System.out.println(message);
    inputStreamReader.close();
    clientSocket.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
    }
    }

    }
    }
```

The Async Task code :

package com.example.client;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //reference to the text field
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   //reference to the send button

    //Button press event listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

    messsage = textField.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
    textField.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank

    try {

     client = new Socket("134.190.162.165", 44440);  //connect to server
     printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
     printwriter.write(messsage);  //write the message to output stream

     printwriter.flush();
     printwriter.close();
     client.close();   //closing the connection

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    });

    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on the PC side to get its IP:

```
String IPfromPC = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

Use that IP in your Andoid app:

```
mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IPfromPC, 4444), 5000);
```

Comment: I tried this : It is giving same error ..
String IPfromPC = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();


     client = new Socket(IPfromPC, 4444);  //connect to server

Comment: Error message :    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)

java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)


java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:371)

Comment: I do all socket stuff on an AsyncTask thread.  You can't do it on the main thread.