# Where should I keep Async file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I am new to android and have a very silly doubt.

I have a android file, a java desktop application file and an asynctask code.

I want to transfer data from android to java desktop server.

all three are java files. SO, my silly doubt is should I keep them under one project, but java and android cant be kept under one. So should i keep android file and asynctask file under one project ?

If no, then i should make a different android project for asynctask ?

How should i run it ? First Asynctask , then server(java desktop app) and then client(android).

I just want to pass data from android device to java desktop server.

Hope I am clear. I am a newbie, so asked it.

Edited:

My asynctask code is :

```
public class Asynctask extends AsyncTask<View, Integer, Socket>
{
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "134.190.162.165";  // Toshiba laptop
    private static final int DEST_PORT = 4444;

    private EditText mTextField;

    /**
     * Store provided views (used later in onPostExecute(...)).
     * 
     * Create socket to communicate with server (blocking call).
     */
    protected Socket doInBackground(View... params)
    {
        // Store provided views.
        if (params.length != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        mTextField = (EditText) params[0];


        // Create socket.
        Socket client = null;

        try
        {
            client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT); // connect to server
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return client;
    }

    /**
     * Write to server.
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter printwriter;
            String messsage;

            messsage = mTextField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
            mTextField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank

            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream

            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();

            client.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is the line  protected Socket doInBackground(View... params) correct ??
I created a class and stored it in under the android project. Now, Should I run all three files ?? And the order should be Server first and then any ?

Answer (score 0):

If by `AsyncTask` you are referring to the Android class, then it should be part of your Android project because that forms part of the code that is supposed to run on the Android device as part of your application. The desktop application should be a separate Eclipse project because you don't want that code included in the .apk file when the Android app is packaged.

Comment: Ok. Yes, it is an android class. How should I run it. First async task ? then server (java desktop app) and then client ?

Comment: @user3316775 - Presumably the `AsyncTask` will try to open a connection to the server, so unless the server is started before that happens, the connection attempt will fail. Depending on how you write the `AsyncTask`, it may just give up or else keep trying. If the latter, it doesn't matter in what order things are started, as long as the server is started before the `AsyncTask` gives up.

Comment: @user3316775 - With that `AsyncTask`, you need to have the server already running for it to succeed. The client can be started before the server, but the `AsyncTask` must not start before the server. (If the client executes the `AsyncTask` right when it starts, then of course the server has to be running ahead of time.)

Comment: Can you please help me with : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816005/transfer-data-from-android-to-java-desktop-application

Comment: @user3316775 - Regarding that other question, it seems like you just need to use an `AsyncTask` to do the connection. You merely need to avoid doing any network activity on the main thread.

Comment: My app is crashing. I run Server first then async task and then client. App crashing. In the server I have kept in catch that "problem in reading", but even this is not displayed. I think I am  running it wrongly. Some silly mistake i am doing @Ted

Comment: @user3316775 - I don't understand--the `AsyncTask` should be part of your client. How can it run before the client? Please start a new question with your current code, explain the exact sequence of operations, and include the exact wording of any error messages (including any logcat stack trace if applicable).

Comment: As you said, I opened a new question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818076/data-from-android-mobile-to-java-application-through-socket

Could you please help me out