# Android Asynctask method does not display the data

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, asyncsocket

```
I tried to display data(string) from android device to java desktop server application. I was successful in that. I tried to find wifi signal strength from wifi access point to android device. I did that too. Now, I need to integrate this both thing. 

First, is the client code where I find the signal strength and pass it to server. First, I run the server. It runs and waits. As soon as I run the client the signal strength from 1st router is displayed and then the app crashes. I have given the error log. 

It crashes because of Async method in the client. This Async task code works well when I try to send string from android mobile to java desktop server. But, here it gives me an error. I think, I have made some simple error.



Client.java

    package com.example.temp;    
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public final static String extra = "com.example.temp.MESSAGE";  
    protected static final long TIME_DELAY = 5000;
    TextView mTextView;
    Handler handler=new Handler();  
    int count =0; String data ="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        handler.post(updateTextRunnable);

        messsage=mTextView.getText().toString();

        new Asynctask().execute(messsage);  
    }

    Runnable updateTextRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (count < 5) {
                WifiManager mainWifiObj;
                mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                    }
                }

                WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
                registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
                        WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                
                List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
                for (ScanResult result : wifiScanList) {
                    if (result.SSID.equals("Dal-WPA2")) {
                        sb.append(result.level);
                    }
                    if (result.SSID.equals("eduroam")) {
                        sb.append(result.level);
                    }
                    if (result.SSID.equals("Dal")) {
                        sb.append(result.level);
                    }
                }               
                count++; mTextView.setText("getting called " +count + sb);
            } else {

            }               
                //----------------code here to send values to java server---
                  handler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY);
                    }
            };



    class Asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "134.190.162.165";
        private static final int DEST_PORT = 4444;

        private EditText mTextField;
        protected Void doInBackground(String... messages) {
          //  if (messages.length != 1) { return null; }
            String message = messages[0];
            Socket client = null;

            try {
                client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT); // connect to server
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Write to server.
            try {
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream

                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}     

The  Error from the log cat I found is : It is in the Async task here.

>FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1  
         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()  
        android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)  
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)  
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)  
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)  


java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.example.temp.MainActivity$Asynctask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
com.example.temp.MainActivity$Asynctask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 Activity com.example.temp.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.temp.MainActivity $1$1WifiScanReceiver@41756998 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
02-17 15:13:52.771: E/ActivityThread(25738): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.temp.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.temp.MainActivity$1$1WifiScanReceiver@41756998 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
 android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1167)
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1154)
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1148)
android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:348)
com.example.temp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:58)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The server just waits for the response and displays the data. With simple string it displays  the data But here, the client crashes so, it is not possible. So, I assume that client code is perfect.

There is no compile time error only run time. In the run(), I call Async method and then do handler.postdelayed, so that code runs again after few second. But it runs correctly till Asynctask class is called In the Async task, it gives me error. 

I am new. It would be great if someone can point out my mistake.

I tried but I am not getting what I should do. I think my logic is correct as individual parts are running. But dont know why async task is not running here.

Thank you in advance.

Edited : The print writer and other sockets closed. 
Still getting the same error.

I have just used class Asynctask and not public class Asycntask, hope there wont be any problem in this.

I just understand from the log file that error is in asynctask background , but exactly the error is not understandable also. 

I dont know where I am getting wrong.

Thanks for the help.
```

fdvkfdnvkkfdnb fdkvj nfdvnjfdknv fdvnfdvnkdfnv fdjkvnfdkjvnjkfdn 
fdjvfdjkv fdvndfkjvn fdlvnkdfvn fdkvnfdnvk fdvknfdkvn
fdvklmfd fdkv flkk fdkvkfl fdkkklvklfdm flvmalsvmaslvv
dfvkfdlkv f lkfdv fdlkvmfdklvm fdvkfdklv dfklvlfdknvkfdnv
dfvknfdklvn dfkvfdkvn fdkvnfdkvn dfkkvnfdknv dfjkvnfdkjnv

Comment: Which is line 114 in MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem arises because you are not properly closing `client` and `printwriter`. (You need to close all streams for the socket as well as the socket itself.) On repeated executions, the `AsyncTask` tries to open a new socket and eventually the OS runs out of resources for doing so because of this failure to close. The call to `new Socket(...)` throws an exception (which you catch) but then `client` remains `null`. Since you don't return after the exception, you then get a `NullPointerException`. My guess is that this `NullPointerException` is what's responsible for the app crash. (This really is just a guess; the info in the error you posted is quite sparse.)

Try this code instead:

```
public class Asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {        
    private EditText mTextField;
    protected Void doInBackground(String... messages) {
        String message = messages[0];
        Socket client = null;        
        try {
            client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write(messsage);
        }
            catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (printwriter != null) {
                try {
                    printwriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                printwriter = null;
            }
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code. Wrote the exact code which i wrote.

Comment: @user3316775 - Try moving the declaration of `Asynctask` out of the `Runnable`. From the looks of it, you could make it a `static` class as well. Also, you should check that `client != null` before trying to open an output stream with it.

Comment: I edited..as u told, u telling something different ?

Comment: @user3316775 - That's what I suggested, yes. If the problem is still there, I don't know what's going on. The error message that you posted is usually followed by additional error lines starting with "Caused by". That's where the actual diagnostic information should be.

Comment: @user3316775 - The edit is correct. Please post the **entire** set of error messages. The error you posted ("An error occurred while executing doInBackground()") is always followed in the logcat with the cause of the error. Without that information, I don't have a way of helping any more.

Comment: I posted the entire set of error messages. One caused is null pointer exception.

Comment: it is       
       try {

                 client.close();

             }

Comment: @user3316775 - Then `client` is `null` at that point. You can put in a check to avoid executing the `close()` if it's `null` or you can catch the `NullPointerException`. However, you have other problems if `client` is `null` that you will need to track down. You might find clues earlier in the logcat.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. From first I am getting the same error. I am unable to get any problem. As individualy, I was able to find the signal strength and also pass value from android device to java app.

Comment: Now , it is showing null pointer on the line :



printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

Comment: @user3316775 - Come on--you can figure this out. Of course you'll get a NPE there if `client` is `null`. You should exit `doInBackground` as soon as you discover that you cannot make a client connection. (Then you can work on diagnosing _why_ you can't make a connection, which is a different issue.)